# How can you avoid repeating type information using c++11's type inference feature to create a shared_ptr instance?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

You can make a pair instance using the new c++11 [`auto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Type_inference) keyword to completely minimalize the typing information that you're supplying to the compiler:

```
auto my_pair(make_pair(10,"yay"));
```

Is there a similar mechanism for creating `shared_ptr`'s?  The only syntax I can find repeats the type information to the compiler 2 times:

```
auto p = make_shared<int>(10);
                       \   \
                        \   ` type information part 1
                         `duplicate type information part 2
```

Which is not as that much better than the pre-c++11 syntax

```
shared_ptr<int> p( new int(10) );
```

**I was thinking that there might be a `make_shared_ptr` template function in the way that there is a [`make_pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/).  Does such a template exist for `shared_ptr`?**

(I'm a bit scared to trying to roll my own because of all the exception safety issues mentioned in the boost docs.  I would also like to avoid creating my own idiolectic template.)

Comment: Perhaps I'm being slow, but where's the type repetition in `auto p = make_shared<string>("Hi\n");`? I honestly don't see how it could be much simpler.

Comment: Post edit: `"Hi\n!"` is a string literal. It is an array of `const char`. How does the compiler know that you want to convert it to a `std::string` rather than any other type of string object that you might need unless you specify the new type? You haven't repeated either type twice.

Comment: The type information part one is only `char *` and not `string` like in the "duplicate" type information.

Comment: You're right, you're right.  I shouldn't have chosen a string.  Changed to int.

Comment: I don't really understand the use case but you could just write your own template for the simple case where you completely infer the shared pointer type from the initializer: `template<class T> std::shared_ptr<T> my_mk_shared( T t ) { return std::make_shared<T>( t ); }`, then you can do `auto x( my_mk_shared(10) );`.

Comment: You may want to use `std::forward` on that parameter, rather than just using it directly.

Comment: Your new example is even worse -- it's using a copy constructor. For any construction that _isn't_ a copy construction, the benefits should be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be scared of exception safety in this case. What you're considering could look like:

```
template<
    typename T
    // for convenience:
    typename Decayed = typename std::decay<T>::type
>
std::shared_ptr<Decayed>
deduce_shared(T&& t)
{
    static_assert(
        !std::is_array<
            typename std::remove_reference<T>::type
        >::value
        , "Array parameters not allowed" );

    return std::make_shared<Decayed>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

which is fairly innocuous. Even returning `std::shared_ptr<Decayed>(new Decayed(std::forward<T>(t)))` is safe, I'm just stealing the optimization opportunity of `std::make_shared`.

Answer (score 8):

You don't.

The type passed to `make_shared` means nothing; that's not nearly enough information to know what type to allocate. Maybe you have some class that you want to use, which just happens to take an `int` as a parameter to its constructor.

`make_shared` does not exist to make typing out `shared_ptr` constructors easier. It exists for two reasons:

1: It makes it much more difficult to do something like this:

```
SomeFunc(shared_ptr<string>( new string("hi") ), shared_ptr<string>( new string("hi2") ));
```

Because of how C++ defines the order of evaluation of the expressions, it is possible that you allocate both string objects before creating the `shared_ptr` temporaries. If one of them throws, you leak memory.

And that's terrible.

Using `make_shared` means that you don't call `new` explicitly. So you cannot possibly get this problem.

2: It allows an optimization, where the `shared_ptr` control block is allocated along with the storage for the object in question. Doing `shared_ptr<string>( new string("hi") )` will allocate 2 blocks of memory: one for the `string`, and one for the internal control block for the `shared_ptr`. Calling `make_shared<string>("hi")` will only allocate one block: both the `string` and the internal control block will be allocated together.

What you're talking about is something more along the lines of a hypothetical `copy_shared`, where you explicitly require exactly one parameter, and you explicitly copy the value. Of course, you would also want a `move_shared` that takes the value by `&&` and uses move-construction.

Comment: I'm sorry, my use of `make_shared` and the `string/const char*` was a distraction.  I was asking if there was something very like `make_pair` which infers _all_ type information  from the parameters for creating `shared_ptr` instances.  Thank you for the information on `make_shared` as I wasn't exactly clear on its usage model ( yes, I need to RTFM more).

Comment: @RossRogers: Demanding complete type inference robs you of the valuable optimization opportunity afforded by the new C++11-style emplacement syntax which takes advantage of perfect forwarding. I'd say it's just not worth it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no duplication in what you've posted. `make_shared<T>` takes the *constructor arguments*, which do not necessarily correspond to `T` itself at all. Even your example demonstrates this - you receive a `shared_ptr<std::string>` but did not pass `make_shared` a `std::string` at all- you passed it a `const char(&)[N]`. This is *not* an ignorable conversion. It does not happen by any string-specific magic. It occurs because and only because a `std::string` can take that in it's constructor. I could write any number of trivial examples to demonstrate this. How about a vector?

```
auto p = make_shared<std::vector<float>>(100); // pass 100 to vector constructor
```

Unless you wish to argue that `make_shared` should be able to infer `int` as it's argument from `std::vector<float>`, which is evidently false because `std::vector<float>` has a number of other single-argument constructors, let alone multiple-argument constructors, or that it should be able to infer `std::vector<float>` from `int`, which also evidently false because any `std::vector<T>` could initialize from `int`, let alone all the other primitives and UDTs which can initialize from `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that the accepted answer is potentially dangerous - it does what it promises to do, but it can cost you dearly - innocuous it is not.

That way, you're **always** forwarding an instance of whatever you want to construct to the copy constructor. It hurts performance, but arguably more importantly it may even bite you in the back.

In case that object passed contains **any** resources already initialized (in place, even)
as fields, and the destructor frees them, then shared_ptrs this ways always point to an object with **no** actual resources.

### Example

Note in this contrived (somewhat RAII ignorant, but we'll get to that) example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<
        typename T,
        typename Decayed = typename std::decay<T>::type
>std::shared_ptr<Decayed> deduce_shared(T&& t){
        static_assert(!std::is_array<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value, "Array parameters are not allowed.");
        return std::make_shared<Decayed>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

class Container{
        public:
                int* pricyResource = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0xBAADDEAD);

                Container(int* pricyResource):pricyResource(pricyResource){
                        cout << "Constructing, with nice resource:" << *pricyResource << endl;
                }

                Container(const Container&){
                        cout << "Copy constructing." << endl;
                }

                ~Container(){
                        cout << "Destructing." << endl;
                        delete pricyResource;
                }
};

int* acquireResource(){
        return new int(9001);
}

int main(){
        auto shared = deduce_shared(Container(acquireResource()));
        cerr << shared->pricyResource << endl;
        cerr << "Destruction / potential segfault (this case) after scope ends." << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

One potential output: (You are not guaranteed that SIGSEGV.)

```
Constructing, with nice resource:9001
Copy constructing.
Destructing.
0xbaaddead
Destruction / potential segfault (this case) after scope ends.
Destructing.
Segmentation fault
```

### ... is that such a big deal?

Of course, should the resource be wrapped in a shared_ptr, things are better - but only slightly. You could also argue the resource should not be initialized outside the class, but I'm sure you can think of a situation where this does not make much sense.

Assuming its protected by a shared_ptr, consider what happens if there is a pool resource users, and the resource is kept alive by the shared_ptrs of the members? 
Well, in case there are no members (no client requests, no entries on a message queue, etc), and a single member is spawned into the pool, the expensive resource blinks in and out of existence - the constructor of the first member creates the resource, then its destructor immediately deletes it. If its copy constructor expects the resource be there, or bothers not to do so, and actually checks whether it exists, and notices it does not, the resource is created / connected to / allocated again.

(You could argue there should be an unique pointer somewhere, and a dedicated "owner" of this resource, and you are right - but let's assume otherwise.)

### Conclusion

All in all, do not do this - there is simply no reason to. 
Use `make_shared<Type(constructor,arguments,of,the,type).`

*Small print*: of course, you could rely on the default constructor doing nothing (or flip flags), and the destructor realizing such an empty state, but doing so would be questionable design.

*Extremely fine print*: I'm aware of SO's policy against responding to answers with answers, but I simply don't have enough rep to comment or edit that answer, and thought I might save some people some time. I also realize other people have objected against the use intent of the OP, but saw none against that particular snippet.